# Warning/Confirmation Prompt before executing Custom Button's VF Popup?

Tags: apex, visualforce, button

I have a custom button on the Account object that, when clicked, renders a VF page in a new window. I'm wondering if it is possible to have a pop-up *before executing the vf page* to have the user confirm what they are about to do, and they can either hit cancel or continue.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the button up to have "Behavior" of "Execute JavaScript" and "Content Source" of "OnClick JavaScript" then you can use a JavaScript [confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) to OK or Cancel the navigation to the new window.

Comment: Is this the only way? Somebody I'm working with told me to avoid using the Execute JavaScript because it rarely works well, and the functionality I want would ideally display a visual force page upon clicking. I'm hoping for an option that involves that. Suggestions?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis In my experience Execute JavaScript always works. But sure you can do something more complicated if you want to.

Comment: The following JavaScript should be fairly self-explanatory in what I'm trying to accomplish. Any suggestions as to why it isn't updating what I'd like? confirm("Are you sure you want to make a new Badge? This will expire the existing one."); {!Account.card_version__c} + 1

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis I don't understand what `{!Account.card_version__c} + 1` is meant to do in JavaScript. Suggest you post a new question with all the relevant information in it.

Comment: Again, the syntax may be wrong but the intent is pretty straight-forward. It's an integer, increment it by one. Apologies if that was not immediately obvious, I don't know what the proper syntax is but I thought that would represent my best guess.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis `{! }` is evaluated at the server side and the resulting constant value is output in the HTML that goes to the client. JavaScript runs at the client-side (the browser). So at best you will be evaluating say 5 + 1 in JavaScript and throwing away the result.

Comment: OK but my question is how do I get this to actually do what I want? I assumed you'd figure I didn't want to throw it away, I want to know how to get this concept to actually make that change to the account. Like I said, I realize syntactically this is not accomplishing anything -- how can I get that incremental value to actually go through and update?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Ask a new question on that. That way hopefully you'll get other people's input.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in the button code--->

var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to this operation?");
if(conf == true){
//write your code
}